# CFBridgingRelease creates issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a piece of code where I am rotating an UIImage inside a UIImageView, The function which is called to rotate the image has this piece of code,

```
CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                               rotatedRect.size.width,
                                               rotatedRect.size.height,
                                               8,
                                               0,
                                               colorSpace,
                                               kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

Then I do this,

```
 CGImageRef rotatedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext); 
 CFRelease(bmContext);
 CFBridgingRelease(rotatedImage);

 return rotatedImage;
```

Before this I was using

```
[(id)rotatedImage autorelease];
```

But that gave me an error

"cast c pointer type CGImageRef to objective c pointer type id error"

I read on it and got to know I need to use CFBridgingRelease, But what it does is it releases my rotated image before returning it hence it gives me a BAD EXCESS , I cannot release after returning as in that case I will never be executing my release statement.

Any idea how can i release rotatedImage?